# Socket.io resource not found: "/socket.io/1/?t=..."

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-ec2, websocket, socket.io

I'm in the process of transforming my first node / socket.io app from working locally, to working remotely, on a server.

---

I've launched the socket.io server (successfully):

```
var socket = require("socket.io").listen(4545);
```

And linked the client to it (successfully):

```
<script src="http://54.186.131.77:4545/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But I'm now getting this error, and I'm not sure what it means or how to fix it:

```
GET http://officeball.biz/socket.io/1/?t=1399501542907 404 (Not Found) socket.io.js:1659

Socket.handshake socket.io.js:1659
Socket.connect socket.io.js:1699
Socket socket.io.js:1551
io.connect socket.io.js:94
(anonymous function) client.js:257
```

And at `client.js:257` is:

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

[It seems to be a common scenario](https://github.com/Flotype/now/issues/190)

---

**What could be the cause of this resource not being found?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `socket = io.connect(http://54.186.131.77:4545);` instead